# Jquery not working when called 1st time, but works if called again for a 2nd time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ive got a WordPress theme Im adding some custom jquery navigation to, Ive got the jquery working inside of an html file, and now Im trying to integrate it into the Wordpress theme.

To do this Ive copied the relevant parts of the JS, css html etc into to correct places, but when I run the site nothing happens, to solve this I can add this call to jquery in the `<head>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

So it would seem that the issue is just to do with jquery not being called, but doing this breaks all the other jquery / js in the site, Ive looked through the `<head>` of the the existing Wordpress theme and found this call to jquery

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/mysitename/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>`

What I cant work out is why my script dosnt run even though the above is in place, but only runs when i do the second jquery call (which ive placed below the localhost one), any ideas why this is happening and how i can resolve it ?

Comment: Your jquery navigation is working with loading jquery via cdn with not removing existing one and then it destroy other jquery stuff but not you navigation. am I correct?

Comment: @ruwanka madhushan - correct

Comment: then, probably it is because you are using two versions of jquery `1.11.1` and `1.11.0` it may produce a conflict. Look at console, are there any error messages? Your navigation code may not work with existing jquery verify that and use only one compatible version of jquery for both your and existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "http://" protocol, rather than the "https://" secure protocol, to access the jQuery CDN?

Comment: hi, I don't have 50 reputation points, yet, to post a comment. That was my first thought though, thank you.